# Mesh doesn't fit well on Models while using shrink wrap

Tags: shrinkwrap

The Mesh doesn't fit well on the surface of my character reference, it's like the Mesh melted inside of my character, I am using Shrinkwrap. any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: the vertices stick to the faces they meet, but the shape of your high-poly is round and may cover your low-poly sometimes, you can give a bit of Offset to your Shrinkwrap if you want to see the lowt-poly

Comment: As moonboots says: Your shrinkwrap offset is 0.  make it some small positive number.  Also, if you want the new mesh to remain above/outside the character, apply it and use the SurfaceDeform modifier.

Comment: Have you Tried the Tangent Normal Project method?

Answer (score 0):

The vertices stick to the faces they meet, but the shape of your high-poly is round and may cover your low-poly sometimes, you can give a bit of *Offset* to your *Shrinkwrap* if you want to see the lowt-poly.